# Rename Terraform Directory

Tags: terraform

I want to restructure my terraform directory -- I'm going to go to multiple regions and break apart a large .tfstate file into smaller ones. As a starting point, I want to take the existing `terraform` folder and rename it to `terraform/us-east-1` so I can add `terraform/ca-central-1/vpc` but as soon as I do, Terraform breaks:

```
$ terraform plan
Error: Error loading modules: module mymodule: open .terraform/modules/f6d6d743c2d8bd836f32baa02d0922f7: no such file or directory

$ terraform init
Initializing modules...
- module.mymodule
Error downloading modules: Error loading modules: module mymodule: open .terraform/modules/f6d6d743c2d8bd836f32baa02d0922f7: no such file or directory
```

I haven't found much about special ways of renaming terraform folders on a search, but I'm not having any luck doing it. Bizarrely, when I've tested a few combinations, sometimes it seems to work on combinations I don't want to use but I haven't figured out exactly when it works and when it doesn't, only that it never works on the name I'm trying to use.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The .terraform folder works with absolute paths. Changing the folder structure will also require to recreate the .terraform folder.

This can be done by either removing the folder and running `terraform init` again.

or

From the [terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/get.html), `terraform get -update` would also resolve this

> The modules are downloaded into a local .terraform folder. This folder should not be committed to version control. The .terraform folder is created relative to your current working directory regardless of the dir argument given to this command.
>
> If a module is already downloaded and the -update flag is not set, Terraform will do nothing. As a result, it is safe (and fast) to run this command multiple times.

Comment: `terraform init` definitely didn't work for me. See my original example in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Near as I can tell, this is the result of having moved the `.terraform` folder. If I remove that, then I need to `terraform init` again, but after that it seems to be behaving. Fingers crossed?